# Comma or Colon?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, editing, format

I am a bit confused as to whether I should use a comma or a colon for the following sentence:

> Art quickly became a world where I could trust my abilities, a world where I can share my emotions and stories.

or

> Art quickly became a world where I could trust my abilities: a world where I can share my emotions and stories.

Which is more correct?  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

**Before edit**

colon = for example = in other words

You can use colon.

**After edit**

The colon : is a punctuation mark consisting of two equally sized dots placed one above the other on the same vertical line. A colon often precedes an explanation, a list, a quotation, or a block quotation. It is also used between hours and minutes in time, titles and subtitles of books, city and publisher in citations, chapter and verse in biblical citations, and for salutations in business letters and other formal letter writing.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_(punctuation)